# Executing for command outputs to many lines

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to execute a command from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).exe, but it outputs to many lines ...

```
for %b in ("AB","FG") do (for /D %a in ("C:\FileStore\%~b*") do (echo %~fa))
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\admin>(for / %a in ("C:\FileStore\AB*") do (echo %~fa ) )
C:\Users\admin>(echo C:\FileStore\AB Map 1 )
C:\FileStore\AB Map 1

C:\Users\admin>(for / %a in ("C:\FileStore\FG*") do (echo %~fa ) )

C:\Users\admin>(echo C:\FileStore\FG Map 2 )
C:\FileStore\FG Map 2
```

But I only want this...

```
C:\FileStore\AB Map 1
C:\FileStore\FG Map 2
```

How can I fix this?

Doing this using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) it works well, but I need to run it from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).

Comment: Precede each command inside `for` with an at-sign: `for %b in ("AB","FG") do @(for /D %a in ("C:\FileStore\%~b*") do @(echo %~fa))`

Comment: ...or without some parentheses: `@for %b in ("AB","FG") do @for /D %a in ("C:\FileStore\%~b*") do @echo %~fa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the implicit echoing of a command, prefix the command with `@`:

```
@for %b in ("AB","FG") do @(for /D %a in ("C:\FileStore\%~b*") do @(echo %~fa))
```

Note that each of the commands on the line needs its own silencing prefix.